# How do I relate a table of events to a table of intervals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spotfire

I need to merge two tables based on overlapping time data, and I don't know how to do this in SQL. I have a table of events and times, such as this:

```
Event_Table
+----------------+-------+
|     Event      | Time  |
+----------------+-------+
| Fire Alarm     | 10:00 |
| Smoke Alarm    | 13:00 |
| Security Alarm | 16:00 |
+----------------+-------+
```

I also have a table of time intervals, such as this:

```
Interval_Table
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| Warden | Shift_Start | Shift_End |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| Jack   | 09:00       | 10:30     |
| John   | 14:00       | 20:00     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

I need to make a table of events which includes which warden was on duty at the time:

```
Output_Table
+----------------+-------+----------------+
|     Event      | Time  | Warden_On_Duty |
+----------------+-------+----------------+
| Fire Alarm     | 10:00 | Jack           |
| Smoke Alarm    | 13:00 | [null]         |
| Security Alarm | 16:00 | John           |
+----------------+-------+----------------+
```

Some Warden shifts might overlap, but that should be ignored; maximum one warden name should be displayed for every event. The tables are very large (~500,000 rows). Any ideas on how this can be achieved with SQL?

Comment: You can't just ignore overlaps, you have to specify which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. Notice how I posted consumable ddl and sample data? You should do this in the future. It makes it a LOT easier to help. Most of time on this was setting up the problem. The query itself was a trivial effort.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Event') is not null
    drop table #Event

create table #Event
(
    EventName varchar(20)
    , EventTime time
)

insert #Event
select 'Fire Alarm', '10:00' union all
select 'Smoke Alarm', '13:00' union all
select 'Security Alarm', '16:00'

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Shifts') is not null
    drop table #Shifts

create table #Shifts
(
    Warden varchar(10)
    , StartTime time
    , EndTime time
)

insert #Shifts
select 'Jack', '09:00', '10:30' union all
select 'John', '14:00', '20:00' union all
select 'overlap', '15:00', '22:00';

with SortedResults as
(
    select * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by e.EventName order by s.StartTime) as RowNum
    from #Event e
    join #Shifts s on s.StartTime <= e.EventTime and s.EndTime >= e.EventTime
)

select *
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
   Event, 
   Time, 
   (select top 1 Warden from Interval_Table where Time between Shift_Start and Shift_End) as Warden_On_Duty 
from Event_Table
```